# attempt to change type="button" to hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

the following code works for my button, which displays an image when clicked:

```
<input type="button" onclick='javascript:showImg("<%# FieldValue %>")' />
```

I want to change this to a hyperlink 'display' but the following code doesnt work.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="displayImg" runat="server" NavigateUrl='javascript:showImg("<%# FieldValue %>")'>Preview</asp:HyperLink>
```

it throws the error:
JavaScript runtime error: Invalid argument.

any help?

Comment: FYI: setting "javascript:" as the protocol inside your `onclick="javascript:` is redundant as all on{EventName} attributes are expecting JavaScript content.

Comment: Have you just tried 'Viewing Source' in the browser to see what is being passed into the Javascript function? Is it passing a string or a literal?  My feeling is that you don't need the '<%' notation inside the <asp: tag, but I'll freely admit this isn't my area of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `NavigateUrl` property, and that's for an URL... use this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="displayImg" runat="server" 
      PostBackUrl="#"
      onclick="showImg('<%# FieldValue %>');return false;">
      Preview</asp:HyperLink>
```

When you're using ASP.NET Controls, you need to stick what they do, but **remember** that you can always use the default HTML controls, in this example:

```
<input type="button" onclick="showImg('<%# FieldValue %>')" value="Preview" />
```

EVen if you want to use this, in your code behind file, just add a `runat="server"` and you can then find the control using it's `ID`.

---

Here's 3 ways of doing it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('hi!')">Preview 1</a>

<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" onclick="alert('hi!')">Preview 2</asp:HyperLink>

<asp:LinkButton runat="server" PostBackUrl="#" OnClientClick="alert('hi!')">Preview 3</asp:LinkButton>
```

this will render:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('hi!')">Preview 1</a>

<a onclick="alert('hi!')" href="#">Preview 2</a>

<a onclick="alert('hi!');" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$MainContent$ctl01", "", false, "", "#", false, true))'>Preview 3</a>
```

where the last option, it will always POST.

Simple, choose the best way to accomplish it, they all do the same.

Comment: just added 3 examples of what you can do... you can simply use `onclick=...` in your current code and set the `NavigateUrl` to `#`.

Comment: "EVen if you want to use this, in your code behind file, just add a runat="server" and you can then find the control using it's ID" - this is incorrect - <%# FieldValue %> will not be parsed as expected. It will give a literal value.

Comment: @geedubb he should use `<%= FieldValue %>` or if inside a control, use the `Eval` or `Bind` property of that control, but in he's question, there is no specification that he's inside a control. **You're assuming** things, there is no need to downvote my answer, as it's correct, just ask the OP why is he using `#`, ask him to ask things correctly...

Comment: @balexandre thanks for taking the time to write that out, the alerts work fine with this, but its not alerts I am looking, When i try to insert onClientClick='javascript:showImg("<%# FieldValueString %>")'> it tells me JavaScript runtime error: Invalid argument. I want to display a picture when clicked

Comment: @John in your answer, there is no mention what's `FieldValueString`, is that a property of the **page**, is that a property of a **control**? we normally use `<%# FieldValueString %>` when we're navigating inside a collection object, for example, rows in the `GridView`, but there is no mention of such in your question, and for that I need to point out that you should use `<%= FieldValueString %>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or...

```
 <a ID="displayImg" onclick='showImg("<%= FieldValue %>")'>Preview</a>
```

Problem is that <%= FieldValue %> won't be parsed properly when it's inside a server tag (asp:hyperlink)

Comment: Thank you for the reply but still getting JavaScript runtime error: Invalid argument.

Comment: I am gettint the error Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right example when you want to bind some value in HiperLink NavigateUrl:
NavigateUrl="javascript:showImg('<%# FieldValue %>')"

Comment: thank you for replying i am using <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:showImg('<%# FieldValueString %>')" onClick='showImg("<%# FieldValueString %>")'>Preview</asp:HyperLink>
 but still geting that runtime error

Comment: Remove onclick. you dont need it.

Comment: Thank you for the help man but it is still giving me that error. what am i doing wrong?